# Doubt regarding some proof in countable and uncountabe sets

Tags: real-analysis

Proof goes as follows -:

**Theroem** - Ig g:A to C which is injective, where C $\subset$ (may or maybe proper) of N, then A is countable infinite

So the main idea of proof is that we define a new function by taking range of function g so as to make it onto. So say $\phi$  :A$\,\to\,$g(A). This is Onto. So i write as A is numerically equivalent to g(A) where g(A) is subset of N. Then my instructor concludes that g(A) is countably infoinite which i donot understand how?

Thanks for helping

Comment: I think you mean that if $A$ and $C$ are sets, $g:A \rightarrow C$ is an injective function, and $C \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, then $A$ is either finite or countably infinite.  To prove this, can you find a way to list the elements of $A$?

Comment: Alternatively, if you know something about cardinality inequalities, you can assert $|A| \leq |C| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$, where the first inequality holds because $g$ is an injection and the second holds because $C \subseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

The result (as written) is false. Let $A=C=\{1\}$ for a counterexample.

What we *can* conclude from the given hypotheses is that $A$ is *countable*--that is, finite or countably infinite--because we have seen that $A$ is equinumerous to a subset of $\Bbb N.$

Alternatively, it may be an additional hypothesis that $A$ is an infinite set, in which case the result *does* follow.